not able to get google map apis pointer
I am displaying certain pointers on a Google map in an angular project, i have to display different colours of the pointers using the colour code, https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|d0e0e3 is one such endpoint where the d0e0e3 is the colour code which renders specific color of pointer, now I get 404 error while hitting the API
I have gone through the google maps documentation but couldn't find the pointer API anywhere, the pointer colors are dynamic and are coming from backend, so i cant store diff colors of pointer images in my local
